# Вопрос по сравнению дат в PHP

Tags: дата, php, sql, mysql

В общем имеем таблицу в MySQL в таблице нас интересует поле Status и поле SendDate. Последнее поле хранит в себе Timestamp. Вопрос, как лучше организовать выборку и сравнение дат. Мне нужно выбирать записи дата которых меньше $current_date так сказать. Как это лучше организовать с помощью запроса SQL на стороне сервера БД, что-то типа вот такого запроса:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Leters` WHERE `Status`='1' AND `SendDate` <" . $current_date;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Но тогда у меня возникает вопрос, как правильней получить $cirrent_date, чтобы он был в правильном формате Timestamp? В общем, подскажите как это лучше сделать. Раньше с такими вещами как-то не приходилось сталкиваться почему-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раньше этим не интересовался, а сейчас действительно понадобилось, вот что надумал :

```
<?php
$sql_get_my_session =   mysql_query("SELECT updated FROM users_online WHERE (NOW() - updated) > 300");
#
echo 'db dates :<br />';
#
while ($fth = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_my_session)) {
    echo $fth['updated'].'<br />';
}
?>
```

**users_online** - таблица из которой происходит выборка.

**NOW()** - специальная функция в **mysql**, которая возвращает текущее время в таком формате : **2007-12-15 23:50:26**

**updated** - колонка в таблице БД, которая содержит в формате **2007-12-15 23:50:26**

**(NOW() - updated) > 300** - запрашиваем из базы строки, со времени изменения которых прошло больше **300 секунд(5 минут)**.

Comment: >updated - колонка в таблице БД, которая содержит timestamp в формате 2007-12-15 23:50:26


понимаешь что написал то хоть? 

Тогда уж не timestamp а просто таблица в формате datetime.

timestamp - это вот так 1328092708 а не 2007-12-15 23:50:26

Comment: ок, исправлю

Comment: >(NOW() - updated) > 300")

я не проверял, но вот это что работает? Оо

Comment: Да, по крайней мере то, что мне было нужно выполняется.

Comment: timestamp в MySQL это как раз таки формат YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss могу кинуть пруфпик, если нужно... Или он в таком виде отображает просто.

Answer (score 0):

используя функцию  
`date`, или strtotime
относительно того, как она лежит в базе и с чем сравнивать

Comment: мне нужно сделать выборку записей у которых SendDate меньше current_date... Т.е. нужно сравнение двух таймштампов.

Answer (score 0):

Функция [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) возвращает текущее время в виде timestamp.

A функция [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php) возвращает заданную дату и время в виде timestamp.

Comment: А как на счет SQL-запроса, такого вида вообще вроде как можно делать запросы?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Leters` WHERE `Status`='1' AND `SendDate` < '$current_date' ";
$sp=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
```

И в $sp получаем массив где данные идут от 0 до n и у каждого аргументы имена полей в БД
пример

```
Array 
(
    [1]
       [Status] => '1'
    [2] 
       [Status] => '1'
    [3] 
       [Status] => '1'

)
```

или получить данные сразу через

```
while($sp=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql)) {

}
```

Насчет mysql_query($sql) сразу в функцию сувать конечно не хорошо, на время теста  нужно так :

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

А сравнивать даты лучше в Тайстампе и уже нужно переводить в привычные человеку даты.

Comment: я знаю как делать запросы и выборку в PHP... не на тот вопрос вы отвечаете. вопрос был конкретно про сравнение дат :)

Comment: >Но тогда у меня возникает вопрос, как правильней получить $cirrent_date, >чтобы он был в правильном формате Timestamp? В общем, подскажите как это >лучше сделать

Вроде как вы писали.. Спросили как правильно получить
А сравнивайте как обычные цифры и все.на то он и таймстамп